# Enter the position for a guide in After Effects numerically

Tags: after-effects

Is there a way to manually type the precise pixel position for a guide, instead of zooming in and dragging it to the correct position?

Answer (score 3):

Updating my answer as this is now possible in CC 2019 onwards:
Create a guide, right click on it and enter a numeric value. Simple!

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, no. I've wished for this many times myself.

Michael Szalapski wrote in a [CreativeCow thread](https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/202/892496),

"At 100% zoom level in the comp viewer, guides move on full pixels, so you can place them on exact pixels right where you want them if you sit them on a null (or solid or whatever). Granted, it doesn't snap, but when I tried it just now, I got it right where I wanted it pretty quickly with a null as a reference. "

That's the best solution I've ever come across. Not what you asked for, I know.

Answer (score 0):

I just write an "O" and align it in the middle with the align tool. Then zoom in and set the guides so there's a perfectly placed cross in the middle of the O. Hope you find this useful.

Comment: If you're aiming for the middle, just turn on the screen safe guides - they give you a cross smack bang in the middle of the comp ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will be available in CC 2019:

Answer (score 0):

You can actually right-click the guide and enter in a numerical position, now !